# Can I draw an annotation in bokeh with data from a ColumnDataSource?

Tags: bokeh, timeserieschart

I'd like to draw a vertical line on my Bokeh plot which gets moved around by javascript in the browser at runtime. (It's a timebar that marks the current time on a time series plot.)

For drawing a static vertical line, I'm using:

```
from bokeh.models import Span
timebar = Span(location=where_I_want_the_timebar, dimension=height)
my_figure.add_layout(timebar)
```

In order to enable the interactivity, I think I need to get the `location` from a `ColumnDataSource`. However, I can't figure out how to do that, because `Span` does not accept a `source` argument.

Alternatively, is there another way for me to move the timebar at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. In python:

```
from bokeh.models import Span
timebar = Span(name='timebar' location=where_I_want_the_timebar, dimension=height)
my_figure.add_layout(timebar)
```

Then in javascript in the browser:

```
let timebar = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name('timebar')
timebar.attributes.location = my_new_desired_location
timebar.change.emit()
```

If someone posts a way to use a ColumnDataSource I will accept that answer.